# Timestamp to date query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I use the query bellow in DB2. How do I do the same query in oracle?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DATE(field) = CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY
```

Comment: I'm guessing based on the tags that `field` in Oracle is defined as some sort of `timestamp` rather than a `date` (which in Oracle always has a day and a time)?  Is `field` a `timestamp`, `timestamp with time zone`, or `timestamp with local time zone`?

Answer (score 0):

If `field` is a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type (both of which have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and the `TIMESTAMP` can also have fractional seconds) then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  field <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
AND    field >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Comment: why not sysdate - 1 ? Is the interval added for timestamp check?

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida You can use `TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1` if you want to but using `INTERVAL '1' DAY` explicitly tells the reader what the dimension of the value being subtracted is. If you were asking why use `TRUNC`, then it is because `SYSDATE` will have a time component and you want to filter between the midnight at the start and end of the day.